# AJAX isn't sending data correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to AJAX some POSTed data to a PHP page, but the data isn't being sent correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<a id="some_id">LINK</a>
```

**Ajax function**

```
mFunction(){    
    $("#some_id").click(function(){
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(thisId);
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'magic.php',
        data: {"thisId" : thisId},
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
       }
     });    
  });  
}
```

**PHP**

`<?php$thatId = $_POST['thisId'];
   print_r($_POST);
 ?>`

So everything should work as I understand but something is wrong.
In console.log(data) I Get the ID so data has been send
But in print_r I get an array of () empty array..

Comment: And the PHP part is where?

Comment: `<?php$thatId = $_POST['thisId']; print_r($_POST); ?>`

Comment: Have you made sure that `P` is part of [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `dataType: "json",` so your ajax call expecting `json` response and thats why you are not seeing anything in response.

use `json_encode();`

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem; I believe OP is saying that `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: @Jack i know but you can see OP using type POST and posting data correctly so this the possible causing...if there's anything else let me know so i can correct it..

Comment: what u mean what is it?? I put in PHP
`echo json_encode($_POST);
$pageid = $_POST['linkId2'];`

Comment: @Froxz so what happened does it worked..??? and i think its `thisId` not `linkId2`

Comment: @Froxz Did you see my earlier comment about `variables_order`?

Answer (score 1):

magic.php

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST` is empty, which seems to be the case here, you should take a look at your configuration file, in particular the [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) setting.

> For example, if variables_order is set to `"SP"` then PHP will create the superglobals $_SERVER and $_POST, but not create $_ENV, $_GET, and $_COOKIE. Setting to "" means no superglobals will be set.

Make sure that `"P"` is part of this setting, i.e.

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

Restart the server after making this change.

Comment: Can't Do that..
`success:function(data){
console.log(data);
}`
I receive object {link:"The_pressed_ID"}
But it success function so it should work(((

Comment: @Froxz You said you saw empty array; besides, the PHP code you've posted in the question doesn't seem to actually give that result in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
data: {"thisId" : thisId},
```

should be

```
data: {thisId : thisId},
```

Comment: @Jack `dataType` is The type of data that you're expecting back from the server, but `data` can only contain plain-object or string, am I wrong ??

Comment: Yeah, object or string. In this case, it's an object; property names in object literals can be quoted (JSON standard) or not.

Answer (score 0):

magic.php

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

html.html

```
 mFunction(){    
   $("#some_id").click(function(){
     var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
     console.log(thisId);
     $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'magic.php',
     data: {thisId: thisId},
     dataType: "json",
     success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
     }
    });    
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you request parameters to the server must is object,

data:

`{thisId: "abc"}`

not:

`{"thisId": "abc"}`

And why do not you put a different name for thisId var in this case?

`var thisId = $(this).attr('id');`
to

`var tId = $(this).attr('id');`

and using it:

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'magic.php',
     data: {thisId: tId},
     dataType: "json",
     success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
     }
    });
```

It coincides with the name of the object passed to the key post, I'm not sure it can be duplicated or not, but I do not choose the same name.

Comment: {thisId: thisId} can be used.